# Calculate the difference if the values in one column match

Tags: r, performance, if-statement, data-manipulation

I have some longitudinal data where the obversions of some individuals are missing at some time points:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), #id2 is missing for time 3 and 5
                 time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 4),
                 value = c(3, 4, 2, 55, 5, 9, 43, 22))
```

I want to calculate the difference between two individuals if they share the same time point, otherwise we pad them with `NA`. The expected outcome is below:

```
 id  time value  diff
  1    1     3    -6  #the time point matches and so calculate the difference
  1    2    46     3  
  1    3     2    NA
  1    4    55    33
  1    5     5    NA
  2    1     9    -6
  2    2    43     3
  2    3    NA    NA
  2    4    22    33
  2    5    NA    NA
```

How do I achieve this in a fast way? I have a much larger dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(id) %>%                                    # make sure id 1 comes first
  group_by(time) %>% 
  mutate(diff = ifelse(n() == 2, -diff(value), NA)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Gives:

> ```
> # A tibble: 8 × 4
>      id  time value  diff
>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
> 1     1     1     3    -6
> 2     1     2     4   -39
> 3     1     3     2    NA
> 4     1     4    55    33
> 5     1     5     5    NA
> 6     2     1     9    -6
> 7     2     2    43   -39
> 8     2     4    22    33
> ```

Comment: That's right. I corrected the `df`. Thank you @Axeman

Comment: If you need all `id == 2` in your table (like your expected output), add `%>% complete(id, time)` (may be slow).